# How to download a file on apple script

Tags: applescript

I want to make an applescript program to make a minecraft server for anyone.

I need to download a file from http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-beta/craftbukkit-beta.jar.

Here is my current code:

```
if the button is "Beta" then
    do shell script "curl -o ~/Desktop/BukkitServer http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-beta/craftbukkit-beta.jar"
end if
```

Comment: You don't say what the problem is. Does the code you have not work? Do the wrong thing? Do the right thing, in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You curl was a bit off + you need to make sure that folder "*BukkitServer*" exists too.

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "BukkitServer" of desktop) then
        make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"BukkitServer"}
    end if
end tell

do shell script "curl -L http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-beta/craftbukkit-beta.jar -o ~/Desktop/BukkitServer/craftbukkit-beta.jar"
```